# How to compile @Library @NonCPS using gradle in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle, groovy, shared-libraries, jenkins-pipeline

I need to verify code changes in pipeline scripts (scripted pipeline), but I'm having a problem with compiling @Library and @NonCPS lines.

While doing task compile within gradle, I got errors:

```
unable to resolve class Library ,  unable to find class for annotation @Library('someLibrary') _

unable to resolve class NonCPS ,  unable to find class for annotation @NonCPS
```

I tried to include some external plugins within dependency like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-cps:2.41@jar'
    compile 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-cps-global-lib:2.4@jar'
    compile 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins:pipeline-utility-steps:1.5.0@jar'
    compile 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-support:2.14@jar'
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    compile "org.jenkins-ci.plugins:job-dsl-core:${jobDslPluginVersion}"
    compile 'org.jenkins-ci.main:jenkins-core:1.609.3'
    compile 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins:build-pipeline-plugin:1.5.6'
    compile 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins:pipeline-build-step:2.5.1'
    compile 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins.pipeline-stage-view:pipeline-stage-view:2.9'
    compile 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-cps:2.41'
    compile 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-cps-global-lib:2.4'
    compile 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins:pipeline-utility-steps:1.5.0'
    compile 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-support:2.14'
}
```

but didn't work as expected.

I'm new to gradle so I might be missing some understanding.

Comment: import com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS
worked for @NonCPS error

Answer (score 7):

The `NonCPS` annotation type comes from the open source [cloudbees/groovy-cps](https://github.com/cloudbees/groovy-cps/blob/846d8d8eed10c57063d50894d2949e9a8fd21ae0/lib/src/main/java/com/cloudbees/groovy/cps/NonCPS.java#L19) repository in the package `com.cloudbees.groovy.cps`.

You could add a compile dependency on something like `compile('com.cloudbees:groovy-cps:1.22')`.

Comment: But what to do for `@Library(String)`?